# Unable to import self created package - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasterprimes'

Tags: python, package, pypi

I have created a package with structure like below:

```
-- gitrepo
     -- subfoldername
          -- __init__.py
          -- abc.py
          -- abc_alternate_ways.py
     -- __init__.py
```

I am using following code in the `./gitrepo/\_\_init\_\_.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./subfoldername")
from subfoldername import abc as fast, abc_alternate_ways as alternate

__all__ = ["fast", "alternate"]
```

I have created a simple package build using following pyproject.toml file

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "pkgname"
version = "0.0.3"
authors = [
  { name="some author", email="some@gmail.com" },
]
description = "Some different description"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.0"
classifiers = [
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 2",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
"Homepage" = "https://github.com/somerepo/somereponame"
"Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/somerepo/somereponame/issues"
```

I have installed python package using `python -m pip install pkgname`. But I am unable to import self created package with `pkgname` - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fasterprimes'`.

Where am I going wrong.

Comment: what is fasterprimes? where is it located in your original code? (is it a dependency that is not listed in the toml)

Comment: Ouch, I was removing the real package name. Changed everything except that. Please take the error as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgname'` when importing

Answer (score 0):

you need to build your package with `poetry build` then you can pip install `./dist/*.egg`

you cannot install with `pip install <pkgname>` unless you have deployed your package to a pypi index that you are using with your pip version (probably just the regular pypi repo, but there are other options as well)

if you just want to install it in your poetry virtual environment you can use `poetry install`

you also should not need to adjust the path like that in the init ...

**if** you did need to however you would probably need to do something more like

```
import sys
import os
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(DIRNAME) # you would not want to add the folder you are trying to import ....
from submodule import something
```

"./subfolder" is going to look for "subfolder" relative to where the script is being run from, not relative to the script